# Swift Combine: Getting only the first value at subscription?

Tags: swift, combine

I have a set of traditional `UIViewController`s and `UIView`s that I’m passing a `Publisher` to:

```swift
class MyModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var product: Product?
}

…

let someView = SomeView(product: self.model.$product)

…

class SomeView : UIView {
    init(product: Published<Product?>.Publisher) {
        self.sub = product.sink { prod in <do stuff when it changes> }
    }
```

I need to do something with one of the properties of `MyModel.product` only once when the view inits, and *not* every subsequent time `product` updates. Is there anything like this:

```swift
    self.pub = product
        .sinkOnSub { prod in <do when creating this subscription> }
        .sinkRemaining { prod in <do subsequent times> }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do it inside the publisher chain if you only need it on subscription? Why not just do it on the line before `self.sub =`?

Comment: @jnpdx I couldn't figure out how to get at the actual field. All I have is the `Publisher` for it. Is there a way?

Comment: Ah, I see. Interesting question.

Comment: I would use `scan` and pass a tuple to indicate which one is first.

Comment: Or just use `handleEvents` to detect when we subscribe.

Answer (score 7):

You can create two subscriptions. In the first one handle the `.first()` value; in the second one - handle remaining with `.dropFirst()`.

```
var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

product
   .first()
   .sink { prod in 
      // handle first
   }
   .store(in: &cancellables)

product
   .dropFirst()
   .sink { prod in 
      // handle remaining
   }
   .store(in: &cancellables)
```

---

Or, if you must use the same `sink`, you can do what Matt suggested in comments: use `Scan` to attach an ordinal number to each value:

```
product
  .scan((0, nil), { (tuple, prod) in 
      (tuple.0 + 1, prod)
  }
  .sink { (n, prod) in
     if n == 1 {
        // handle first
     } else {
        // handle remaining
     }
  }
  .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscription is working while token is stored in cancellables. When you get value just delete token to cancel subscription:

```
var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

product.sink { prod in 
      // handle first
      cancellables = []
   }
   .store(in: &cancellables)
```